# Checking if TWO keys already exist in flutter Firestore using a future

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using a future to check for a specific key in my flutter firestore databse, which I saw from a different answer on here:

```
  Future<bool> doesPersonAlreadyExist(String name, DocumentSnapshot document) async {
  final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(currentUserId)
    .collection('dislikes')
    .where('nopeId', isEqualTo: document['id'])
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments();
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  return documents.length == 1;
}
```

I can then return a futurebuilder to return different kind of widgets depending on the result of the doesPersonAlreadyExist() future:

```
      return FutureBuilder(
  future: doesPersonAlreadyExist(currentUserId, document),
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> result) {
  if (!result.hasData)
    //return empty container
  if (result.data)
    //return empty container
  else
  //return as normal
```

**I want to** check in two different collections in the Future doesPersonAlreadyExist. Right now I am only checking in a collection called 'dislikes', but I also want to check in a collection called 'likes'. Is this possible with my current method, and if not, how so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from making two different queries, one after another, then checking that both of their conditions are met.